# normal button that acts like menubutton python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write code that you can turn a normal Tkinter button into a dropdown menu but the dropdown menu button is in the main window, not in the menu bar. kind of like notepad++ how the menu bar is on the window, but I am making a dropdown button like that but that shows in the window. Can someone help? I don't really know how to explain this, but I am a beginner. I am using python and Tkinter on pycharm on a mac.

here is a video I made to explain more:
https://www.hippovideo.io/video/play/nuvNU03a6Hg7_oQC39uy1wgopPijjQQGCLH18VC0KiA

Comment: are you aware that tkinter has a `Menubutton` widget?

Comment: Do you mean a *Context Menu* that open at `Pointer` position clicked `<Button-2>`.

Comment: I mean like, in mac on pycharm, when I run the program, the menubar shows up in the top of the screen like where the apple logo is. I am trying to make my own version of notepad++ text editor and I have all the code for it, but, the menubar doesn't show up in the actual window. so I am trying to replicate that. how do  I am making a dropdown button like that but that shows in the window?

Comment: Bryan Oakley, Yes I am. Read my just added response above

Answer (score 0):

You can create popup-menus with `menu.tk_popup(x, y)`.
So just add `master.bind('<Button-3>', lambda e:menu.tk_popup(x, y)`.
`x` and `y` are values which you choose. If you want to place the menu at the mouse-pointer, you can use `master.geometry()`, but to be honset, I have no idea how to use `master.geometry()` exactly. But there are other Solutions too, e.g. `tkinter.Spinbox()`.

Comment: I had another idea to try, how could I make a frame under the button show up with different buttons to press. So, I left click on the file button I created, then the frame will show up beneath the file button and have different options /(buttons) to do different commands.